# Why can I not update settings on datepicker using change in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, datepicker

I am trying to create two different sets of settings for datepicker(http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) when the user picks different radiobuttons in a group.

Here's my code:

```
$("input[name='shipping_time_english']").change(function(){
   datepicker();                                                     
});

function datepicker() {
  if ($("input[name='shipping_time_english']:checked").val() == '1-3 work days') {
    alert('1-3 days selected');
    var firstDay = '+1';
    var lastDay = '+3';
  } else if ($("input[name='shipping_time_english']:checked").val() == '4-8 work days') {
    alert('4-8 days selected');
    var firstDay = '+4';
    var lastDay = '+8';
  }

  $("#rush_needed_by_english").datepick({
    minDate: firstDay,
    maxDate: lastDay
  }); 
} //end datepicker function
```

I know the change event is working, because the alerts are alerting each time I change the value of the radiobuttons. For some reason, the settings on the datepicker are whatever the first value on the radiobuttons is that I select. As soon as I change the radiobutton value again, the settings on the datepick don't change as I would like.

Why can I not update settings on datepicker using change in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$("#rush_needed_by_english").datepick({
    minDate: firstDay,
    maxDate: lastDay
});
```

to

```
$("#rush_needed_by_english").datepick('option', {
    minDate: firstDay,
    maxDate: lastDay
});
```

You just got the call wrong. Recheck the documentation for the plugin here [jQuery Datepicker Reference](http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html#global) and then scroll to the functions documentation. It's the second signature there.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to call the date picker plugin differently:

```
$("#rush_needed_by_english").datepick('options', {
  minDate: firstDay,
  maxDate: lastDay
});
```